# How to get joint, speed, acceleration values of cartesian path?

Tags: joint, path, acceleration, ros-kinetic, cartesian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working with OMPL and waypoints. [This tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html)  explains how to use them. Everything working fine and the plan from start to goal is executed. The terminal tells me the following:

```
[INFO] [1550520522.690988548]: Computed Cartesian path with 3 points (followed 100.000000% of requested trajectory)
[ INFO] [1550520522.692175575]: Execution request received
[ INFO] [1550520522.788166419]: Fake execution of trajectory
[ INFO] [1550520524.088018603]: Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED ...
```

Is it possible to see all the joint values for these 3 points? Speed and deceleration of joints?
Maybe it is possible to write these values in a .txt file with an external python file?
Any suggestions are welcome, i just need these values for each point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315977/how-to-get-joint,-speed,-acceleration-values-of-cartesian-path?/) by [DieterWuytens](https://answers.ros.org/users/38350/dieterwuytens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-02-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DieterWuytens](https://answers.ros.org/users/38350/dieterwuytens/) on 2019-02-18**:
For example: in RVIZ I can see that the last link is rapidly changing it's orientation. From 0.25 to -0.25 in approximately 1 second. How can i plot these values in an external file to analyze them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're referring to the [Cartesian Paths](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html#cartesian-paths) section of that page: the `plan` result variable that you get from your invocation of `move_group.compute_cartesian_path(..)` contains all of the information about the joint poses that make up the Cartesian motion.

You should be able to `print(..)` it, iterate over it, etc.

> I'm currently working with OMPL and waypoints.

Please note that OMPL (or any of the planners actually) is *not* used when you use `compute_cartesian_path(..)`. It's essentially performing a linear interpolation between your waypoints. That is rather different from the "random search" that OMPL does.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DieterWuytens](https://answers.ros.org/users/38350/dieterwuytens/) on 2019-02-18**:
I didn't know that! How do I integrated OMPL or other planners with these waypoints then? What kind of planner is used for calculation of the path?
print(plan) does work, thanks.